# AppleScript returns same window for same beginning text

Tags: applescript

i have an issue. I need to loop through the windows of Apple´s Stickies Application. I am using Applescript.
But if i have multiple notes, with the same beginning, then i get only the properties of the first one. (Still loops through the true number of notes).

```
tell application "Stickies"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Stickies"
            set allWindows to every window
            try
                repeat with awindow in allWindows
                    set m to value of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of awindow
                    log m & "

"
                end repeat
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Error on uploading an example image, so inserted it as script

```html
<a href="https://ibb.co/hMJwC5Y"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/MhxQ9TB/zjo.webp" alt="zjo" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: Stickies is not scriptable, so there isn't anything to uniquely identify a window, such as an ID property.  The window reference is just using the name, which is the first line in the note, so the first window that matches is what is getting used.

Answer (score 0):

using a different loop gives me unique references.

```
tell application "Stickies"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Stickies"
            repeat with awindow in windows
                set m to value of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of awindow
                log m & "

"
            end repeat
            
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

EDIT:
using a different repeat

Comment: Still buggy: Properties get mixed. Window gives me sometimes the text of Stickies_B and the size & position of Stickies_A

Comment: The order of the notes will change as they are opened and closed, as that moves the level/index of the window.  The size will depend on whether the note is open, but the position shouldn't change.